# Incorrect value from count in posrgres on enum rows

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following query written in sqlalchemy

```
_stats = db.session.query(
            func.count(a.status==s.STATUS_IN_PROGRESS).label("in_progress_"),
            func.count(a.status==s.STATUS_COMPLETED).label("completed_"),
            ) \
            .filter(a.uuid==some_uuid) \
            .first()
```

this returns (7, 7) which is incorrect it should return (7,0) i.e. in_progress_ = 7, completed_ = 0

When I do this in two queries I get the correct values

```
_stats_in_progress = db.session.query(
            func.count(a.status==s.STATUS_IN_PROGRESS).label("in_progress_"),
            ) \
            .filter(a.uuid==some_uuid) \
            .first()

_stats_in_complete = db.session.query(
            func.count(a.status==s.STATUS_COMPLETED).label("completed_"),
            ) \
            .filter(a.uuid==some_uuid) \
            .first()
```

The corresponding SQL also does not work when using the two counts

```
SELECT count(a.status = 'IN_PROGRESS') AS in_progress_, 
    count(a.status = 'STATUS_COMPLETED') AS completed_
FROM a
WHERE a.uuid = '9a353554a6874ebcbf0fe88eb8223d33'
```

this returns 7,7 too, while if I do the query with just one count I get the correct values.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `count(a.status = 'IN_PROGRESS')` should be `count(*) filter (where a.status = 'IN_PROGRESS')`. As long as `status` is not NULL your code is equivalent to `count(*)`

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name this appears to work with count('*') NOTE * must be a string in sqlalchemy.